# ASP.NET Core 2.1 App succeeds in Building and Running Locally but fails to Publish to IIS via Web Deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.1 App that I want to publish on IIS8 via WebDeploy. When I publish, this is the error I get:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Web deployment task failed. ((1/15/2019 2:18:40 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)

> (1/15/2019 2:18:40 PM) An error occurred when the request was
>   processed on the remote computer. The server experienced an issue
>   processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more
>   information.  ManagementStudio    C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.503\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets    139

I tried looking around and found this in the temp file

> 1/15/2019 3:01:59 PM System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window
>   for more details.    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__127.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---
>
> ===================

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? I can run it locally but am I missing something? I've looked around and it seems like this error doesn't happen often?

Comment: what is the publish settings you are using? have you tried changing deployment mode and/or target runtime options?

Comment: I am using the ones my server produced and also, I have tried changing it from x64 to self contained and the same issue persists.

Comment: "_Build failed. Check the Output window for more details_", what is the info in the output window? additionally, you may try publish to local folder then upload files to the server via ftp client. I faced similar issues and solved it this way.

Comment: The output window produces plenty of text but nothing seems to be an error. Is publishing to a local folder the only way to bypass this issue?

Comment: no not the only, but the workaround that did it for me at least :)

Comment: Is it possible to do CI with this method?

Comment: frankly speaking, I don't know! this can be another question for the community.

Comment: Publish it manually to the server to simulate the issue. I mean `Local folder` to `Server`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem just by updating the "TypeScript SDK for Visual Studio 2017" from 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258